# what is the error in javascripts i had already define the function but it could not find the defination

Tags: javascript

[hat is the error in  i had already define the function but it could not find the defination please help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdtM8.png)

```js
< script language = "JavaScript"
type = "text/javascript"
src = "JavaScript.js" >
  var inp = document.getElementById('inp');
var conv = document.querySelectorAll('conv');

function convWt() {
  var val = inp.value;
  conv[0].value = parseFloat(val * 1000);
  conv[1].value = parseFloat(val * 2.2046);
  conv[2].value = parseFloat(val * 1000000);
  conv[3].value = parseFloat(val * 0.0011023);
  conv[4].value = parseFloat(val * 35.274);
} <
/script>
```

```html
<center>
  <h1>Weight Converter</h1>
</center>
<center>
  <p>Welcome To Online Weight Converter</p>
</center>

<center><label>Weight In Kg:</label>
  <form id="myForm">

    <input id="inp" type="number" />
    <input type="button" value="convert" onclick="convWT()" />

    <table>

      <tr>
        <td>Weight In Grams:</td>
        <td><input id="conv" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Weight In Pound</td>
        <td><input id="conv" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>MiliGram:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="conv" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Us Ton:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="conv" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ounces:</td>
        <td><input id="conv"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="Rest Form" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').reset()" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  <p><b/> You Can Press Reset Button For Another Conversion
  </p>
</center>

</body>

</html>
```

what is the error in the above code?
the error is uncaught references

hat is the error in  i had already define the function but it could not find the defenation please help

Comment: I'm voting to close this answer because contains one typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstable as I say `convWt()` is not the same as `convWT()`.
Then, you should never give the same `id` to each of your input. 
Try to make this like :

```js
var inp = document.getElementById('inp');
var convGram = document.getElementById('convGram');
var convPound = document.getElementById('convPound');
var convMiliGram = document.getElementById('convMiliGram');
var convTon = document.getElementById('convTon');
var convOunce = document.getElementById('convOunce');


function convWt() {
  var val = inp.value;
  
  convGram.value = parseFloat(val * 1000);
  convPound.value = parseFloat(val * 2.2046);
  convMiliGram.value = parseFloat(val * 1000000);
  convTon.value = parseFloat(val * 0.0011023);
  convOunce.value = parseFloat(val * 35.274);
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h1>Weight Converter</h1>
</center>
<center>
  <p>Welcome To Online Weight Converter</p>
</center>

<center><label>Weight In Kg:</label>
  <form id="myForm">

    <input id="inp" type="number" />
    <input type="button" value="convert" onclick="convWt()" />

    <table>

      <tr>
        <td>Weight In Grams:</td>
        <td><input id="convGram" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Weight In Pound</td>
        <td><input id="convPound" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>MiliGram:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="convMiliGram" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Us Ton:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="convTon" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ounces:</td>
        <td><input id="convOunce"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="Rest Form" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').reset()" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  <p><b/> You Can Press Reset Button For Another Conversion
  </p>
</center>
```

It's longer to write, yes, but it's at best.

Answer (score 2):

Your onClick refers to a non-existent function because of a typo, look at the case of the ref 'convWT' vs the func def 'convWt'

Comment: i dont understand??

Comment: @ArslanKhanAfridi look at the last letter of these 2 words...  `convWT` and `convWt` - one is `T` and the other is `t`.  They need to be **the same**.

Comment: @ArslanKhanAfridi No - it would not be an error.  Something you are telling us in not correct.

Comment: HtmlPage1.html:55 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined at fun (HtmlPage1.html:55) at HTMLInputElement.onclick (HtmlPage1.html:17) fun @ HtmlPage1.html:55 onclick @ HtmlPage1.html:17 HtmlPage1.html:55 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined at fun (HtmlPage1.html:55) at HTMLInputElement.onclick (HtmlPage1.html:17) – Arslan Khan Afridi

Answer (score 2):

Your are trying to execute javascript inside a script tag that is already loading a javascript file. That is not possible. Try loading the js file and in another script tag, use your code. Something like this:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript.js"></script>
<script>
  var inp = document.getElementById('inp');
var conv = document.querySelectorAll('conv');

function convWt() {
  var val = inp.value;
  conv[0].value = parseFloat(val * 1000);
  conv[1].value = parseFloat(val * 2.2046);
  conv[2].value = parseFloat(val * 1000000);
  conv[3].value = parseFloat(val * 0.0011023);
  conv[4].value = parseFloat(val * 35.274);
} 
</script>
```

Also in your HTML part you call **convWT()** but the functions name is **convWt()** without capital T.

Hope that helps.

EDIT: The variables **inp** and **conv** may be null / undefined, because you DOM is not loaded when the js code is executed. The "easiest" way is to use jQuerys **ready** function. It will wait until the DOM is rendered and executes your code. FYI: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: HtmlPage1.html:55 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
    at fun (HtmlPage1.html:55)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (HtmlPage1.html:17)
fun @ HtmlPage1.html:55
onclick @ HtmlPage1.html:17
HtmlPage1.html:55 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
    at fun (HtmlPage1.html:55)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (HtmlPage1.html:17)

Comment: As mentiond in the edit, your DOM is no loaded when the js is executed. Try something like this: 

`function convWt() {
  var inp = document.getElementById('inp');
var conv = document.querySelectorAll('conv');
var val = inp.value;
  conv[0].value = parseFloat(val * 1000);
  conv[1].value = parseFloat(val * 2.2046);
  conv[2].value = parseFloat(val * 1000000);
  conv[3].value = parseFloat(val * 0.0011023);
  conv[4].value = parseFloat(val * 35.274);
}`